# Replace Having Cause with Where Clause

Tags: php, sql, symfony, where-clause, having-clause

Please i have some trouble in my project in symfony

How can i replace having clause wuíth where clause in this code above cause having clause dont work white paginator in symfony

...

...

```
 public function getAllClients($all = true, $user = null)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
```

//

```
    $qb->select('u, count(ls.id) as nbr')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'u')
        ->join(Client::class, 'c', Join::WITH, 'c.user = u.id')
        ->join(LicenceShop::class, 'ls', Join::WITH, 'ls.client = c.id')
        ->groupBy('u.id')
        ->having('nbr > 1');



    $qb->andWhere('u.roles LIKE :roles');
    $qb->setParameter('roles', '%"ROLE_CLIENT"%');

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

Thanks you

When i use having clause symfony response like that

[Cannot count query that uses a HAVING clause. Use the output walkers for pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAU13.png)

And this the function

```
enter code public function show($id = null, UserRepository $userRepository, Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
{




    if($id)
        $user = $userRepository->find($id);
    else
        $user = $this->getUser();

    $client = $user->getClientInfo();
    $myClients = $userRepository->getAllClients(false, $user);

    $myClients = $paginator->paginate(
        $myClients,
        $request->query->getInt('page_c', 100)
    );





    $referal = null;
    $licences = null;
    if ($client) {
        $referal = $client->getReferal();
        $licences = $client->getLicences();
    }

    //$licences = $module->getLicences();
    return $this->render('resellers/show.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'ResellersController',
        'user' => $user,
        'client' => $client,
        'referal' => $referal,
        'licences' => $licences,
        'my_clients' => $myClients,


    ]);


}
```

Comment: *How can I replace `having` clause with `where` clause*? In a nutshell: you can't. The `having` can operate on aggregate expression, which the `where` clause cannot do. You might want to elaborate on the problem that you are having with pagination.

Comment: Thanks you so i need to check my paginator :)

Comment: I don't know  symphony, but with raw  SQL, you can change "having" clause to another outer select with "where" clause.
These two will work equally.
[1variant] Select t.a from t group by t.a having count(\*)>2
[2variant] Select t2.a from (Select t.a,count(*) as c from t group by t.a) as t2 where t2.c>2
Maybe it will help you